# How to deploy SAS code using Jenkins without building

Tags: jenkins, deployment, sas, bitbucket

I am wondering if it it possible to use Jenkins to deploy without testing/building. We have a SAS application, and would like to use Bitbucket as version control, and like an automated pipeline to send out a notification and push the code to the server once it is committed. Is Jenkins able to do all these without test/build?

Comment: The question is quite broad... Maybe chop it down to more manageable bits. We use Jenkins to run SAS jobs regularly. So... The answer is yes?

Comment: @pinegulf May I ask what's your pipeline and jenkinsfile like? I am new to Jenkins, and the Jenkins application is managed by another team, and the pipeline is predefined, when we try to use it it force us to use maven to build, I am not sure if this is required for all Jenkins pipeline, but we have a work around for the build step. But we kept failing at the testing step. We tried to play around with the deploy.sh, deploy.yml, and jenkinsfile, etc. But not sure what's the best way. I would assume Jenkins would allow me to build a pipeline with just the deploy step without build/test.

Comment: Sure... I can't just hand over the whole script, but in general the idea is this: We launch script from jenkins, which has all the input parameters: Which program and `sysfunc` variable. Script ssh:s production machine launches SAS with given parameters. It's not SAS server, but desktop version.